# How to redirect from plugin page

Tags: plugins, redirect

After processing form data in one of plugin file I need to redirect to some other page. When I used wordpress function or php wp_redirect()/header() it shows me error like "header already send" html already start printing before this file.
So How can I redirect after processing form data in plugin file.

Comment: hook your form processing to an action that runs before the page is printed.

Comment: Thanks @Milo. My problem solved by adding a hook. Added my answer what I implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Added hook to process all form values and than redirecting as per process result:

Added below PHP code in theme/functions.php:

```
function process_form(){
 //code goes here
}
add_action( 'admin_post_appointment_form_process', 'process_form' );
```

And added/updated below html to form:

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="<?php echo home_url()?>/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="appointment_form_process">
```

Thanks for @Milo comment.